# Keyboard not getting displayed in Android and BlackBerry on element focus

Tags: javascript, android, ios, blackberry, ibm-mobilefirst

At the launch of an application I need the keyboard to be appear on the screen.

I am able to accomplish this in iOS, where I set the focus on a text field and the keyboard is appearing. However in Android and BlackBerry the keyboard is not getting displayed even though the text field is getting focused.

I have used the below code to set focus:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    document.getElementById("mglTxtEmailAddr").focus();
}, 200);
```

Comment: This code does not work in iOS Simulator either.

Comment: @IdanAdar : Okay but i've tested on device it's working fine can you please help me achieve my goal to put the keyboard up at the time of very first launch of an application

Comment: I've been trying for some time now. Did not yet succeed.

Comment: @DhavalParmar what version of Worklight are you using?

Comment: Yoel, from what I read online, this is actually by design more-or-less. That is, in mobile webviews focus() is intentionally not bringing up the keyboard. The end-user is expected to make a conscious click event to bring it up. Looking for a workaround...

Comment: @IdanAdar I added a workaround assuming is using WL 6.2 and newer.

Answer (score 3):

**Android**
Assuming you are using Worklight 6.2 or later you can use the following code code to show your keyboard on focus for Android.

**Javascript:**

```
document.getElementById('mglTxtEmailAddr').addEventListener('focus', function(){
  WL.App.sendActionToNative('showKeyboard',{});
});


setTimeout(function(){
    document.getElementById("mglTxtEmailAddr").focus();
}, 200);
```

Inside your activity class generated by Worklight Studio, at the end of your onCreate function add the following action receiver.

**YourActivity.java:**

```
WL.getInstance().addActionReceiver(new WLActionReceiver(){
  @Override
  public void onActionReceived(String action, JSONObject arg1) {
    if("showKeyboard".equals(action)) {
      InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        if (inputMethodManager != null) {
            inputMethodManager.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
        }
    }
  }
});
```

**iOS**

For iOS in your AppDelegate class, inside your `wlInitDidCompleteSuccessfully` just add the following code:

```
[cordovaViewController.webView setKeyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction:NO];
```

Comment: Ohhhh very nice! :) Now do the same for iOS. The only exception would be BlackBerry which does not have SendAction support. big +1!